# Numpy array vs python list with time measurement

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, numpy, arraylist

I have read about numpy array runs faster than ordinary code performed in python. I have a large data to send a function with return value. I test it with numpy index and boolean and with python, I should expect to run the task faster with numpy function but in my test is not the case. Why does it run slower?

```
from time import time
import numpy as np

def stress(STEEL_E_MODULE, strain_in_rebars, STEEL_STRENGTH):
    STRESS =  STEEL_E_MODULE * strain_in_rebars
    if STRESS <= - STEEL_STRENGTH:
      stress = - STEEL_STRENGTH
    elif STRESS >= - STEEL_STRENGTH and STRESS < 0:
      stress = STRESS
    else:
      stress = min(STRESS, STEEL_STRENGTH)
    return stress

def stressnumpy(STEEL_E_MODULE, strain_in_rebars, STEEL_STRENGTH):
    STRESS = np.array([ STEEL_E_MODULE * strain_in_rebars,  STEEL_E_MODULE * strain_in_rebars])
    Result = np.array([ - STEEL_STRENGTH,  STRESS[1], min(STRESS[1], STEEL_STRENGTH)])
    cond1 = STRESS[0] <= - STEEL_STRENGTH
    cond2 = (STRESS[1] >= - STEEL_STRENGTH) & (STRESS[1] < 0)
    arr = [cond1, cond2, True if cond1 == False and cond2== False else False]
    return Result[arr][0]

tg1 = time()
for n in np.arange(-1000,1000,0.01):
   y = stressnumpy( 2, n, 20)
tg2 = time()
print("time with numpyfunc:", tg2-tg1)


tg3 = time()
for n in np.arange(-1000,1000,0.01):
   x = stress( 2, n, 20)
tg4 = time()
print("time with func:", tg4-tg3)
```

Time with both functions:

```
time with numpyfunc: 1.2981691360473633
time with func: 0.1738882064819336
```

I expect to get opposite running time?

Comment: Creating arrays from lists takes time.  Iterating through arrays is slower than through lists.  Using the compiled `numpy` methods to operate on whole arrays is fast.  So saying arrays are faster than lists is an over simplification.  You have to use arrays right to gain the speed.

Comment: That is obviously, what the time difference tells. `I have to use arrays right`, are there a guidances that explain how arrays should be used?

Comment: Adding to what @hpaulj has stated, you have mostly used direct comparison between a couple of numbers (elements of arrays) per run, rather than operating on arrays as a whole. It's in those scenarios (e.g. large matrix multiplications) that numpy comes into its own.

Comment: @navneethc. I interpret your answer, that stuff on internet is misguiding and specification must add it to with large 2d, 3d and etc numpy wins.

Comment: A lot of stuff on the web is wrong and one has to learn to identify the useful bits. :-) Did you try starting with the Numpy docs? https://numpy.org/devdocs/user/whatisnumpy.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's misguiding to say that a code with arrays runs faster. In general, when people speak about code going faster with Numpy arrays, they point out the benefit of vectorizing the code which can then run faster with Numpy performant implementation of functions for array operations and manipulation. I wrote a code that compares the second code you provided (I slightly modified it to save values on a list in order to compare the results) and I compared it to a vectorized version. You can see that this leads to a significant increase in time and the results given by the two methods are equal:

```
from time import time
import numpy as np

# We use a list and apply the operation for all elemnt in it => return a list
def stresslist(STEEL_E_MODULE, strain_in_rebars_list, STEEL_STRENGTH):
  stress_list = []
  for strain_in_rebars in strain_in_rebars_list:
    STRESS =  STEEL_E_MODULE * strain_in_rebars
    if STRESS <= - STEEL_STRENGTH:
      stress = - STEEL_STRENGTH
    elif STRESS >= - STEEL_STRENGTH and STRESS < 0:
      stress = STRESS
    else:
      stress = min(STRESS, STEEL_STRENGTH)
    stress_list.append(stress)
  return stress_list

# We use a numpy array and apply the operation for all elemnt in it => return a array
def stressnumpy(STEEL_E_MODULE, strain_in_rebars_array, STEEL_STRENGTH):
  STRESS =  STEEL_E_MODULE * strain_in_rebars_array
  stress_array = np.where(
    STRESS <= -STEEL_STRENGTH, -STEEL_STRENGTH,
    np.where(
      np.logical_and(STRESS >= -STEEL_STRENGTH, STRESS < 0), STRESS,
      np.minimum(STRESS, STEEL_STRENGTH)
    )
  )
  return stress_array

t_start = time()
x = stresslist( 2, list(np.arange(-1000,1000,0.01)), 20)
print(f'time with list: {time()-t_start}s')

t_start = time()
y = stressnumpy( 2, np.arange(-1000,1000,0.01), 20)
print(f'time with numpy: {time()-t_start}s')

print('Results are equal!' if np.allclose(y,np.array(x)) else 'Results differ!')
```

Output:

```
% python3 script.py
time with list: 0.24164390563964844s
time with numpy: 0.003011941909790039s
Results are equal!
```

Please do not hesitate if you have questions about the code. You can also refer to the official documentation for [numpy.where](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.where.html), [numpy.logical_and](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.logical_and.html) and [numpy.minimum](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.minimum.html).

Comment: Thanks alot to your fantastic reply and with improvement of code. Indeed `numpy.where, numpy.logical_and and numpy.minimum` build-in function work well and make it fast. This piece of code in my real code took time and slow my performance with this new improvement is appreciated and performs the task as it is meant to be.

Comment: You are very welcome I'm glad it helped you in solving your computation time problem.